# Finding completely dissimilar permutations

Tags: permutation

For a sequence of n distinct elements, like for example {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1}, where n is even, it is possible to identify n permutations of the sequence that are completely dissimilar from each other. If n is odd, then it is possible to identify n-1 such permutations. Note, this is just a claim and not yet a fact.

By completely dissimilar (which might not be accurate), I mean that there is no "adjacent and ordered pair" of elements, like (0,1), (2,3) and (n-3, n-2), from a certain permutation that repeats in any of the remaining permutations.

For example:

If n=2, then we can identify {0, 1} and {1, 0} as two completely dissimilar permutations.

If n=3, then we can identify {0, 1, 2} and {2, 1, 0} as two completely dissimilar permutations.

If n=4, then we can identify {0, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 1} and {3, 2, 1, 0} as four completely dissimilar permutations.

If n=5, then we can identify {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 4, 2, 0, 3}, {3, 0, 2, 4, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 0} as four completely dissimilar permutations.

I will like to know:

1) Is there a general rule or algorithm to find, given a sequence, any n (if n is even) or n-1 (if n is odd) completely dissimilar permutations of that sequence?

2) Is there a formal definition of this problem?

Comment: Do you mean "sets of dissimilar permutations" ? For example, <{0,1,2}, {1,0,2}> would qualify as well, if I understand your definition. And then you would be looking for maximal such sets, i.e. set of maximum size with mutually dissimilar permutations. Is it what you mean ?

Comment: @arbautjc: Yes, that understanding applies very well. I used <{0,1,2}, {2,1,0}> instead so to put in some pattern! I emphasized on a number of n (or n-1) of such permutations because I think that is the maximum.

Comment: Is your example really correct? You said "no [...] elements like (0, 1)", but all permutations (including the {0,1})  in the example n=2.

Comment: None that 'repeats', yes. (0,1) and (1,0) have no repeated "adjacent and ordered pair". (0,1,2,3) and (2,0,1,3) have (0,1) repeating, and therefore are not completely dissimilar (as per the informal definition).